# Export Project Template command line VS 2012

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2012, command-line, export, project

How can I run export project template having Visual Studio 2012 via command line? Unfortunately, Projectgen.exe file is absent

Comment: Hi Robinson, 
Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: unfortunately, wasn't

Comment: Are there any updates?